# Jquery on Keypress add Class to closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i need to add class to the closest Div on keypress Function
 this is my code 
It adds Class to the first div 
I need to add class based on the positon

This is my Jquery Code

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
var direction = null;

// handle cursor keys
if (event.keyCode == 37) {
// go left

  $("#sad").closest('div').addClass('left');
 alert("left");
} else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
  // go right
  alert("right");
}


});
```

This is Html Code

```
<div id="content">
<article id="1"><div id="sad">1</div></article><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <article id="2"><div id="sad">2</div></article><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<article id="3"><div id="sad">3</div></article><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<article id="4"><div id="sad">4</div></article><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<article id="5"><div id="sad">5</div></article><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<article id="6"><div id="sad">6</div></article><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

It should add class to that div which is nearest to the cursor

Comment: lol... you can't have multiple elements with the same ID. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: And if you want it to add the div closest to the cursor, it will be much harder than you think.

Comment: Check 9gag.com they trigger votes on keypress events